# ASP.NET MVC3 - connection establishment with SQL Server 2008 R2 database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

How to connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database from an ASP.NET MVC3 application?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: I tried the concept used to establish connection between aspx page abd db using ADO.net @jrummell

Comment: Linq To Sql, Entity Framework, Dapper and the list goes on...But seriously +1 to @jrummell.

Comment: I used the concept of ADO.net which is used to establish connection in asp.net and sql server2008 db which is not working in this scenario  @jrummell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Data First approach to connect to the Database. You have your database ready in SQL Server. Once your Database is ready, then you can get all the Database entities into the Application, by follwing this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489.aspx

Its only a starting point! Hope this helps!